# How to create a deployment package with SQL scripts in IIS

Tags: microsoft-web-deploy, iis-10, webdeploy-3.5

Using IIS-10, Web Deploy v3.6, Windows 10.

It is an ASP.NET Website (not application) using SQL Server 2014 for the back-end.
I was able to successfully create and deploy the package, but without SQL scripts. Could not find any info on how to do it for including SQL scripts in the package. Here is what I have tried:

1. In IIS, under 'Default Web Site', select my web application.
2. On the right hand side, click on 'Export Application'.
3. Click on 'Manage Components'. Choose 'dbFullSql' as Provider name. For Path, enter connection string.
   eg: Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testuser;Password=test@345;

When clicked on OK, nothing happens. The processing icon keeps showing. It had to be closed using task manager.
[image]
Also tried with the path of the .sql file, instead of connectionString. But no idea about what parameters to be entered& how /where to mention the connection string.

I would appreciate if anyone could guide me with the right procedure.